# Add column to df with matching information from another df (elegantly, without loops)

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find a way to add a column to df1 with information from df2, conditional on the content of each row in df1 without looping through df1.

Specifically, I want to add general information from df2 ("mammal") as a new column to already existing specific information in df1 ("tiger").

Following code works, but I am looking for are faster/vectorized/more elegant version of it, because it's (of course) very slow.

```
for (i in (1:nrow(df1))) {

 subCategories <- unlist(df1$categories_split[i])
 currentAggrCategories <- unique(df2[df2$subcategory %in% subCategories, 2])

 if (length(currentAggrCats) == 0 ) {
  currentAggrCats <- NA
 }

 df1$aggregatedCategories[[i]] <- currentAggrCats

}
```

Data looks like this:

```
df1:
name  sex categories_split
===== === ================
john  m   c(tiger)
clara f   c(crocodile)
ben   m   c(butterfly, metalmarks)

df2:
subcategory category
=========== ============
tiger       mammal
crocodile   reptile
butterfly   insect
metalmark   insect
```

Note that, due to the data structure (which is unfortunately given), there might be multiple hits in df2 which might be unique or not.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlist and match the column from `df1` to the data in `df2`

```
idx <- match(unlist(df1$categories_split), df2$subcategory)
```

Add the re-listed matches to the original data; this exploits `unlist()` / `relist()` semantics to retain the original geometry.

```
df1$aggregate <- relist(df2$category[idx], df1$categories_split)
```

Use either `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when constructing df1, or `as.character(df2$category[idx1])` during the relist to avoid coercion of the factor to integer. Post-process as needed, e.g.,

```
df1$aggregate = lapply(df1$aggregate, unique)
```

Use `vapply(df1$aggregate, unique, character(1))` if the expectation is that the aggregate column contains a single element.

Answer (score 0):

here is a base solution:

```
#unlist the categories_split column
namedf <- do.call(rbind, by(df1, df1$name, function(x) {
    data.frame(name=x$name, sex=x$sex, categories_split=unlist(x$categories_split))
}))

rownames(namedf) <- NULL

#perform lookup
namedf$category <- df2$category[match(namedf$categories_split, df2$subcategory)]

namedf
```

or a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df2[
    df1[.(name, sex), .(categories_split=unlist(categories_split)), by=.(name, sex), on=.(name, sex)],
    on=c("subcategory"="categories_split")]
```

data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name=c("john","clara","ben"),
    sex=c("m","f","m"))
df1$categories_split <- list("tiger", "crocodile", c("butterfly","metalmark"))

df2 <- read.table(text="subcategory category
tiger       mammal
crocodile   reptile
butterfly   insect
metalmark   insect", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The output is very close to what I am looking for. Is there anyway to avoid permanently expanding each row of df1 that has multiple values in categories_split? In your sample code that would mean not to have a ben.1 and ben.2 row in the final output.

Comment: @Jim you can use `rownames(namedf) <- NULL` to remove the rownames